# How to solve cloud defense CRITICAL SEVERITY from pom,xml

Tags: security, sonarqube, pom.xml, crlf-vulnerability

CRITICAL - org.yaml:snakeyaml - Improper Input Validation
VULNERABILITY
CRITICAL
CWE-20
CVE-2022-1471
CVSS
9.8

Introduced through: org.yaml:snakeyaml :1.27
Discovered on: Dec 1, 2022, 11:15 AM
License(s): Apache-2.0
Exploit: 3.9
Fixed in: Not fixed
Remediation: is not available

SnakeYaml's Constructor() class does not restrict types which can be instantiated during deserialization. Deserializing yaml content provided by an attacker can lead to remote code execution. We recommend using SnakeYaml's SafeConsturctor when parsing untrusted content to restrict deserialization.

I searched on internet but not got any right solution. i'm getting this cloud defense CRITICAL SEVERITY. so want help in that how we resolved it.